# Sudo command in terminal (Mac) - make executable

Tags: macos, fonts, terminal, executable, sudo

I would like to run the following commands in terminal from a desktop executable. Can this be done even though password entry is required?

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
atsutil server -shutdown
atsutil server -ping
```

Comment: Sure, consider adding a line into `/etc/sudoers` so you can run `atsutil` without a password, something like `YourUserId ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/atsutil`

Comment: I ended up using Apple Script Editor to solve the issue - do shell script "/usr/bin/atsutil databases -remove; /usr/bin/atsutil server -shutdown; /usr/bin/atsutil server -ping;" with administrator privileges